# comparing column values based on other column values in pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([['M',2014,'Seth',5],
         ['M',2014,'Spencer',5],
         ['M',2014,'Tyce',5],
         ['F',2014,'Seth',25],
         ['F',2014,'Spencer',23]],columns =['sex','year','name','number'])

print df
```

I would like to find the most gender ambiguous name for 2014. I have tried many ways but haven't had any luck yet.

Comment: I would like to find the most gender ambiguous name for 2014, the above dataframe is just part of a very large dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## NOTE: I do write a function at the end of my answer, but I decided to run through the code part by part for better understanding.

---

## Obtaining Gender Ambiguous Names

First, you would want to get the list of gender ambiguous names. I would suggest using set intersection:

```
>>> male_names = df[df.sex == "M"].name
>>> female_names = df[df.sex == "F"].name
>>> gender_ambiguous_names = list(set(male_names).intersection(set(female_names)))
```

Now, you want to actually subset the data to show only gender ambiguous names in 2014. You would want to use membership conditions and chain the boolean conditions as a one-liner:

```
>>> gender_ambiguous_data_2014 = df[(df.name.isin(gender_ambiguous_names)) & (df.year == 2014)]
```

---

## Aggregating the Data

Now you have this as `gender_ambiguous_data_2014`:

```
>>> gender_ambiguous_data_2014

  sex  year     name  number
0   M  2014     Seth       5
1   M  2014  Spencer       5
3   F  2014     Seth      25
4   F  2014  Spencer      23
```

Then you just have to aggregate by number:

```
>>> gender_ambiguous_data_2014.groupby('name').number.sum()

name
Seth       30
Spencer    28
Name: number, dtype: int64
```

---

## Extracting the Name(s)

Now, the last thing you want is to get the name with the highest numbers. But in reality you might have gender ambiguous names that have the same total numbers. We should apply the previous result to a new variable `gender_ambiguous_numbers_2014` and play with it:

```
>>> gender_ambiguous_numbers_2014 = gender_ambiguous_data_2014.groupby('name').number.sum()
>>> # get the max and find the list of names:
>>> gender_ambiguous_max_2014 = gender_ambiguous_numbers_2014[gender_ambiguous_numbers_2014 == gender_ambiguous_numbers_2014.max()]
```

Now you get this:

```
>>> gender_ambiguous_max_2014

name
Seth    30
Name: number, dtype: int64
```

Cool, let's extract the index names then!

```
>>> gender_ambiguous_max_2014.index
Index([u'Seth'], dtype='object')
```

Wait, what the heck is this type? (HINT: it's `pandas.core.index.Index`)

No problem, just apply list coercion:

```
>>> list(gender_ambiguous_max_2014.index)
['Seth']
```

---

## Let's Write This in a Function!

So, in this case, our list has only element. But maybe we want to write a function where it returns a string for the sole contender, or returns a list of strings if some gender ambiguous names have the same total number in that year.

In the wrapper function below, I abbreviated my variable names with `ga` to shorten the code. Of course, this is assuming the data set is in the same format you have shown and is named `df`. If it's named otherwise just change the `df` accordingly.

```
def get_most_popular_gender_ambiguous_name(year):
    """Get the gender ambiguous name with the most numbers in a certain year.

    Returns:
        a string, or a list of strings

    Note:
        'gender_ambiguous' will be abbreviated as 'ga'
    """
    # get the gender ambiguous names
    male_names = df[df.sex == "M"].name
    female_names = df[df.sex == "F"].name
    ga_names = list(set(male_names).intersection(set(female_names)))
    # filter by year
    ga_data = df[(df.name.isin(ga_names)) & (df.year == year)]
    # aggregate to get total numbers
    ga_total_numbers = ga_data.groupby('name').number.sum()
    # find the max number
    ga_max_number = ga_total_numbers.max()
    # subset the Series to only those that have max numbers
    ga_max_data = ga_total_numbers[
        ga_total_numbers == ga_max_number
    ]
    # get the index (the names) for those satisfying the conditions
    most_popular_ga_names = list(ga_max_data.index)  # list coercion
    # if list only contains one element, return the only element
    if len(most_popular_ga_names) == 1:
        return most_popular_ga_names[0]
    return most_popular_ga_names
```

Now, calling this function is as easy as it gets:

```
>>> get_most_popular_gender_ambiguous_name(2014)  # assuming df is dataframe var name
'Seth'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what do you mean by 'most gender ambigious', but you can start from this

```
>>> dfy = (df.year == 2014)
>>> dfF = df[(df.sex == 'F') & dfy][['name', 'number']]
>>> dfM = df[(df.sex == 'M') & dfy][['name', 'number']]
>>> pd.merge(dfF, dfM, on=['name'])
      name  number_x  number_y
0     Seth        25         5
1  Spencer        23         5
```

If you want just the name with highest total number then:

```
>>> dfT = pd.merge(dfF, dfM, on=['name'])
>>> dfT
      name  number_x  number_y
0     Seth        25         5
1  Spencer        23         5
>>> dfT['total'] = dfT['number_x'] + dfT['number_y']
>>> dfT.sort_values('total', ascending=False).head(1)
   name  number_x  number_y  total
0  Seth        25         5     30
```

Comment: The code above doesnt work but ill explain the problem more, I need to find the name for 2014 that has the highest number of males and females.

Comment: what's the 'highest number of males and females'? do you mean just total number of both males and females? then `df[df.year == 2014].groupby(['name'])['number'].sum()` will do

Comment: No, I dont want to do this.  For example, Pat is both a male and female name. I want to find the name that has the most both males and females

Comment: ok, what's your desired output then, if you use one in the question as an input

Comment: ok @Fungie you really have to define you question, what's 'most both males and females'? Suppost Pat is 10 males and 6 females and Sam is 8 males and 8 females. What do you want to choose? Understanding a question is half an answer